How to deal with Axios vulnerabilities in 1.0.0 - 1.5.1 and >= 1.3.2 versions?
When I run npm install, I have a moderate vulnerability, how can I fix it?
1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

# npm audit report

axios  1.0.0 - 1.5.1
Severity: moderate
Axios Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wf5p-g6vw-rhxx
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/axios

1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

However, when I run npm audit fix, I get a worse vulnerability:
# npm audit report

axios  >=1.3.2
Severity: high
Server-Side Request Forgery in axios - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8hc4-vh64-cxmj
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/axios

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Would you mind helping me solve these Axios vulnerabilities?

Is just updating to the latest version of Axios (1.7.3 at this moment) not sufficient? Presumably these issues have been dealt with.

The high severity vulnerability was disclosed yesterday. There hasn't been enough time to fix it yet. Your options are either waiting for an update that fixes the vulnerability, or evaluating if and how those existing vulnerabilities affect your project and then choosing the Axios version based on that.

@nbokmans I had already tried that by running npm update and I get a high vulnerability.

I prefer using version 1.3.1 at the moment because it only has a moderate vulnerability and not high like 1.7.3 latest at the moment. @GuyIncognito

Have you read and understood https://jeffhacks.com/advisories/2024/06/24/CVE-2024-39338.html? Is your application actually vulnerable? If you are not using axios on the server to make requests with urls constructed from attacker-controlled inputs, you have no issue.

1.7.4 has been released, you can upgrade the CVE has been fixed

Thanks, @Adri. Now version 1.7.4 has been released, and the high vulnerability has been fixed.
I ran:
npm audit fix

And no vulnerabilities any longer!
